# How to pass a variable in the selector id?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to pass the selected value in select element in variable idd and then use it later. But it is not getting stored in the variable. I tried to check the value in the alert function but even alert function is not getting called.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(function(){
      $("select.ctlJob").change(function(){
        $.getJSON("select.php",{id: $(this).val(), ajax: 'true'}, function(j){
          var options = '';
          for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
            options += '<option value="' + j[i].optionValue + '">' + j[i].optionDisplay + '</option>';
          }
          var idd=$(this).val();
          //alert(idd);
          $('select#'+ idd).html(options);
        })
      })
    })
    </script>
```

Comment: The value of `this` inside of `$.getJSON()` does **not** refer to the `select.ctlJob` element. It has a new scope and new context. Store a reference like `var $that = $(this);` before your `$.getJSON()` part, and then use `$that` if you want to reference `select.ctlJob`...or just move your `var idd` line outside of the `$.getJSON()` block

Answer (score 3):

You are not able to get the value as the `this` in your context does not refer to the **select**. You'll need to do the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(function(){
  $("select.ctlJob").change(function(){
    var selectBox = $(this);
    $.getJSON("select.php",{id: $(this).val(), ajax: 'true'}, function(j){
      var options = '';
      for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
        options += '<option value="' + j[i].optionValue + '">' + j[i].optionDisplay + '</option>';
      }
      var idd=selectBox.val();
      //alert(idd);
      $('select#'+ idd).html(options);
    })
  })
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this - (*moved `var idd=$(this).val();` outside of `getJSON`*)

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(function(){
      $("select.ctlJob").change(function(){
        var idd=$(this).val(); 
        $.getJSON("select.php",{id: $(this).val(), ajax: 'true'}, function(j){
          var options = '';
          for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
            options += '<option value="' + j[i].optionValue + '">' + j[i].optionDisplay + '</option>';
          }
          //alert(idd);
          $('select#'+ idd).html(options);
        })
      })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, now it's working fine. Thanks. But what is the explanation for this?

Comment: @Lovy that is because you are trying to use `$(this)` in `getJSON` context, so it doesn't refer to the select being changed

Answer (score 0):

This is a scoping problem, and, you only need to access the selected value once.  This code accesses the value in the *change* handler, then uses it in the getJSON *response* handler, which is a child-scoped function.  All child-scoped functions have access to their parent scopes, which is why *val* is defined in the response handler function.

```
$(function(){
  $("select.ctlJob").change(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();    
    $.getJSON("select.php",{id: val, ajax: 'true'}, function(j){
      var options = '';
      for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
        options += '<option value="' + j[i].optionValue + '">' + j[i].optionDisplay + '</option>';
      }
      $('select#'+ val).html(options);
    });
  })
})
```